# Specifying the host in Rails performance tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, performance-testing

I have been trying to use the Rails profiling tools. I am using a very simple example taken from the docs at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html that looks like this

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

# Profiling results for each test method are written to tmp/performance.
class BrowsingTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
  def test_homepage
    get '/'
  end
end
```

I then run the test using

```
rake test:profile
```

but it crashes with the following error

```
Error during failsafe response: undefined method `controller_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I suspect that the problem is that the app serves multiple domains and so simply using get '/' is not enough information to resolve the url back to a controller/action - it needs a host as well.  However the usual ways of specifying a host (@host, @request.host, default_url_options[:host]) either don't work or cause another error (eg @request is nil).

I have also tried entering the full url. I have the different hosts defined as constants in the test environment so this looked something like

```
get "http://#{HOST_1}/"
```

In this case the rake task completed successfully but no profiling information appeared on the command line and no files were generated.

I haven't really used the profiling tools in Rails much so I am hoping I am missing something obvious.  Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Cheers